# sequelize belongsToMany giving TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize with express, I have defined my model like this

```
"use strict";

var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Order = sequelize.define("Order",
        {
            status: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER
            },
            notes: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING
            }
        },
        {
            classMethods: {
                associate: function(models) {
                    Order.belongsTo(models.User);
                    Order.belongsTo(models.Address);

                    Order.belongsToMany(models.Items);
                }
            }
        }

    );
    return Order;
}
```

I am getting following error message when trying to run my app

```
Order.belongsToMany(models.Items );
     ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at sequelize.define.classMethods.associate (models/order.js:18:7)
at models/index.js:24:19
at Array.forEach (native)
at Object. (models/index.js:22:17)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
```

My index.js file is same as one given is express example here: https://github.com/sequelize/express-example/blob/master/models/index.js

My item model looks like this:

```
"use strict";

var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Item = sequelize.define("Item", {
      title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      mrp: {
        type: Sequelize.DECIMAL,
        allowNull: false
      },
      sp: {
        type: Sequelize.DECIMAL,
        allowNull: false
      },
      desc: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      skuId: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      type: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      merchantId: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      categoryId: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      }
    }
  );
  return Item;
}
```

I have also tried giving belongsToMany in app.js but it does not work. All other associations are working correctly.
Please help.

Comment: What version of sequelize are you using? How are you calling `associate` ?

Comment: Version is sequelize@2.0.0-rc1, associate gets called from index.js which is same as https://github.com/sequelize/express-example/blob/master/models/index.js

Comment: Hmm, orders.js looks fine to me. Can you post your code for `Items`?

Comment: added item model code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a typo in order.js, you want `Item` not `Items`. Like this:

```
Order.belongsToMany(models.Item);
```

Also, you might get a deprecated message asking you to define the `through` param for this `belongsToMany`, eg like this:

```
Order.belongsToMany(models.Item, {
    through: 'OrderItems'
});
```

Lastly, `belongsToMany` was introduced in sequelize version 2.1.0, [it seems](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/commit/3f9b34ddb85869201fd7756936f9a33982da7742#diff-d840a21d7bd81bf7bf32ffc4744c3e01).

Comment: Still the same error :( ..  I dont know why just belongsToMany doesn't work while all other associations are working.

Comment: I've actually cloned the repo and gotten your code to work on my end with the typo fix. I'm not sure what to say. You could try attaching a debugger (eg `node-inspector`) to confirm that the line number of the reported error is correct, and also verify that `Order` and `Order.belongsToMany` are defined as expected.

Comment: Note also that in the sample there's a `Task.belongsToMany(models.User);` that appears to work. I'd recommend also trying to understand where the differences are between your `Order` and the sample's `Task` model.

Comment: Incidentally my version of sequelize is older than the current version that gets downloaded through npm. I upgraded sequelize and it worked. Thanks ..